# Colour-maps in Gnuplot and Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, gnuplot

I have a data file containing three columns. I'd like to plot (1st, 2nd) and use the 3rd to produce a colour-map. That is, each point in the plain takes a colour that depends on the value in the third column.

Using Gnuplot, I can easily do that:

```
gnuplot> set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
plot "output.dat" using 1:2:3  with points palette
```

For a set of data I get something like this:
[image]

Now, is there a straightforward way of doing this in Mathematica?

Comment: For future Mathematica-related questions you can try [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).  Most of the Mathematica activity has moved there.  Your question will be noticed sooner and will get more replies.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. Will do next time.

Comment: @stupidity If you want to include the legend as well you could have a look at the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar) on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I started looking at `ColorFunction`, but it requires a Joined->True, odd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct it from graphics primitives:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {20, 3}];

(* rescale 3rd column to be between 0 and 1, if needed *)
data[[All, 3]] = Rescale[data[[All, 3]]];

Graphics[{PointSize[.03], {ColorData["ThermometerColors"][#3], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ data}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Regarding the colour bar:

The built-in colour bar functionality is not excellent.  You can read abut it [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html).  There's an alternative implementation [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=24).  [My question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/sizing-cells-in-a-graphicsgrid-graphicsrow) may also be useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and demonstration. However, I tried this  with the data that produced the plot I've included before. But all points appear to be red. It's like the third point is constant, but that's not the case, it varies from 0 to 100. I'd really appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Ok never mind, I've done it: Graphics[{PointSize[.02], {ColorData["Rainbow", 
      Rescale[#3, {0, 100}, {0, 1}]], Point[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ DATA}]..... Many thanks

Comment: @stupidity Yes, that was the solution.  I had to leave yesterday and didn't have time to update. Sorry about that.  I updated the post now.